# Importing css classes to react?

Tags: css, reactjs

I joined a project where my predecessor imported css classes to react.js files.

```
import {
  hero,
  heroInner,
  // ...more imports
} from "./Hero.css";
```

Later on he used it in `classNames cn()` and they are in charge of a lot of the website's conditional styling.

```
className={cn(
          heroInner,
          "d-flex align-items-center text-center text-md-left text-white"
```

can you explain how should I use it? And how does this pattern work?

Comment: you should read https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#readme

Answer (score 1):

To import class as variables he must be using [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). You probably can read what it does in there, but in short, it imports the css and generate an object with the classes you can use on your components.

[classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) is simple utility to conditionally apply a class to a component, but it also helps "joining" classes together.

```js
cn(heroInner, "d-flex align-items-center text-center text-md-left text-white")

// is pretty much the same as

`${heroInner} d-flex align-items-center text-center text-md-left text-white`
```